# yii:if and else in ajax and foreach

Tags: php, yii

when I added **else** in my code **if** does not work properly and will process only the first part of the array

```
Array ( [0] => php [1] => yii9 [2] => milsss [3] => msa [4] => klk )
```

in this only php is checked !

```
   foreach ($columnsArray as $u)
          {
              $masterCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
              $gname=$this->group;
              if($this->group == $u)
              {
                 $this->addError('group' ," $gname already registered");
                 $masterCommand->reset();
                 $masterCommand->insert('group',array(
                     $this->group=>'1',
                 ));
                 $masterCommand->reset();
                 $this->newId=   $masterCommand->select('max(id)')->from('group')->queryAll();
                 $this->newId= $this->newId[0]['max(id)'];
                  break;
              }
```

this is **else**.

```
  else {
       $this->addError('group' ," $gname not registered");
       break;
       $masterCommand->reset();
       $masterCommand->addColumn('group' , $gname , 'int(1)');
       $masterCommand->reset();
       $masterCommand->insert('group', array(
            $this->group=>'1',
       ));
       $masterCommand->reset();
       $this->newId = $masterCommand->select('max(id)')->from('group')->queryAll();
       $this->newId=   $maxId[0]['max(id)'];
      }  
}
```

In this two-part How do I make changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error must be cleared First
 Then  later  AddError  show again

```
 if ($this->group == $u)
                {
                 $this->clearErrors('group');
                 $this->addError('group' ," $gname already registered");
                 $masterCommand->reset();
                 $masterCommand->insert('group',
                          array
                                  (
                                       $this->group=>'1',
                                   ));
                  $masterCommand->reset();
                  $this->newId=$masterCommand->select('max(id)')->from('group')->queryAll();
                  $this->newId=$this->newId[0]['max(id)'];
                  $test_status=TRUE;
                      continue;
                   }
if($test_status==FALSE)
{
     $this->clearErrors('group');
     $this->addError('group' ," $gname not registered");
     continue;
}
```